# Why doesn't my binding source exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use a binding source to display info from one forms DataGridView into another form that opens for editing. The code for the form with the DataGridView is as follows:

```
private void GetTestData()
{
    int appointmentID = (int)cbAppId.SelectedValue;
    int testID = 523;

    try
    {
        theTest = ResultController.GetTestInfo(appointmentID, testID);
        resultsBindingSource = null;
        resultsBindingSource.Add(theTest);

        openTestList = ResultController.GetOpenTestList(appointmentID);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = openTestList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

I am trying to take the data from this binding source and carry it over to this form:

```
public int appointmentID;
public Result result;

private void frmEnterTestResults_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resultsBindingSource.Add(result);
}
```

I am, however, getting the error that resultsBindingSource does not exist in the current context.

How can I resolve this? I need to carry the object from the row that is clicked on over to the form that opens upon clicking.

Comment: I assume the object is of type Test class ? and the DataGridView displays Test objects, when you click on a row you want to display an edit form that will edit the previously selected object, right ?

Comment: And what is that Result type? You need to post some more code or clarification